# I want to deploy an Azure Functions that will be used in a Logic Apps, are there any details I should be aware of before I start working?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I keep deploying but getting error.

[image]
The only clue is I am supposed to have log files when I run the function, but I cant seem to generate them.

Please advice.